# GCC segmentation fault in parallel program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, parallel-processing

This a simple parallel program in c.

I am using ubuntu and gcc for compiling.

The program takes input for number of processes, and creates and ask for same number of numbers from the user.
Then each process is used to calculate the factorial of each number.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int factorial(int n)
{
    int fact=1;
    int i;
    for(i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
    {
        fact=fact*i;
    }
    return fact;
}

int main()
{
    int process_id;
    int num_process;
    int pid;
    int i;

    printf("\nEnter No. of Process : ");
    scanf("%d",&num_process);

    int num[num_process];

    for ( i=1; i < num_process; i++ )
    {
        printf("\nEnter %d Number : ",i);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    for ( i=0; i < num_process; i++ )
    {
        pid=fork();
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            perror("Error forking");
            return -1;
        }
        else if(pid > 0)
        {
            waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nFactorial of %d is : %d", num[i], factorial(num[i]));
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Never heard of segmentation fault, can someone explain it what does it mean ?

Comment: When computing a factorial, you should not start at 0.

Comment: You never heard of segfaults? Hard to believe, since the first hit on Google points to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault You usually get segfaults when dereferencing NULL pointers or reading from/writing to unallocated memory (like past the end of the array.)

Comment: Also start using a debugger. I like gdb.

Comment: ...did you just fix the posted program? Does it still segfault? If so, you should post what you did to fix it as an answer instead of just modifying your code. if it still crashes, make it clear that you are seeing a different crash with an EDIT tag. Either way, please don't modify the posted code to "fix" it because it invalidates the answers.

Comment: Please take the habit to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. And BTW it is not `gcc` which is segfaulting, it is your own program.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for ( i=1; i <= num_process; i++ )
{
    printf("\nEnter %d Number : ",i);
    scanf("%d", num[num_process]);
}
```

is problematic.  The valid indices for `num` are 0 to num_process - 1.  Change the loop to:

```
for ( i=0; i < num_process; i++ )
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `factorial` function, `fact` is not initialized.  Also

```
 scanf("%d", num[num_process]);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%d", &num[num_process]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A description of segmentation fault can be read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

A fault is here:

```
   scanf("%d", num[num_process]);
```

Because you are counting from 1 - Arrays start at zero

This line `for ( i=0; i <= num_process; i++ )` will give you too many processes.

**ALSO** `fork` creates another process - so therefore the program is not parallel - you need to use threads. Please google it.

Comment: You don't need to use threads, you just need to use `fork` correctly.  (Have each child write its output rather than trying to have the children write back into the parent's array of results.)